# Multiple Image upload restrict up to 10 images

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

How to add multiple image upload in magento 2 and restrict to only 10

```
  <field name="images">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">default_image</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="celebrities/image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```